# If I alter MySQL table column to increase size, will it delete data in the column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, alter-table

I have a varchar column that needs more space.  How can I increase the size of the column (the number of characters it can have inserted into it), and not lose the data that is in there?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out this [StackOverflow post.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279568/how-can-i-modify-a-size-of-column-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't delete the data by default.

Comment: Milhous has shared a link that'll show you as a comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

When you try to increase column size, it doesn't affect data. while decreasing column size, it should be affected