# mysql: how to truncate the length of a field

Tags: mysql, field, truncate, alter

```
Alter table merry_parents change mobile mobile char(10).
```

When I do the above I'm getting error:

> #1265 - Data truncated for column 'mobile' at row 2

How can I truncate my mobile field to char(10)? Currently it is char(12).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The error is telling you that there is data 12 characters long in row 2 (and probably others) so it's stopped the alter command to avoid losing data.

Try updating your table using `SUBSTRING()` to shorten the column. It's unclear why you want to do this as you'll lose data, but this will truncate the data to 10 characters long:

```
UPDATE merry_parents SET mobile=SUBSTRING(mobile, 1, 10)
```

Then run your alter command:

```
ALTER TABLE merry_parents CHANGE mobile mobile char(10).
```

Comment: thank you. That worked! :) I'm working with test data so it is alright if i'm losing data. :)

Comment: See My table Having a field with gender char(1) , I want to make it gender enum('m','f','o') what should i do ?
Its showing truncating error while alter directly from char to enum

Answer (score 5):

**If you are ok with truncating the data at 10 characters** - you can update the column first, then resize it

```
UPDATE <tablename> set mobile = left(mobile, 10);
```

Then run your alter statement.

Comment: See My table Having a field with gender char(1) , I want to make it gender enum('m','f','o') what should i do ? Its showing truncating error while alter directly from char to enum

Answer (score 4):

If you are willing to just have the data truncated, you can do it in one step by using the IGNORE option on the ALTER:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE merry_parents MODIFY mobile char(10);
```

Comment: If you're not using an ancient version MySQL this won't work. IGNORE was deprecated in 5.6 and removed in 5.7. see: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7395

Answer (score 0):

You have data that has more characters than the length of the column that you are trying to alter it into.

Or you have a null value in the specified field.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14742