# Trim data which is longer than the column length in MySQL

Tags: mysql, trim, sql-mode

I'm inserting data into a table in MySQL using the following query,

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE CSVImport FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES  TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

But when the length of a particular field is greater than the column length it fails as expected. Is there any way to trim the length and set to the length of the column. I know that I can change the sql_mode. But when I do that it will effect to other validations as well. And also it will applied to the whole mysql server as well.

1) Is there any way to apply the sql_mode only to a particular table?

2) Is there any way to achieve this without changing the sql_mode?

Comment: Why not make the column longer

Comment: due to the storage problems. Also we can't say exactly the biggest length.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE merry_parents SET mobile=SUBSTRING(mobile, 1, 10)

from [mysql: how to truncate the length of a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611100/mysql-how-to-truncate-the-length-of-a-field)