# MySQL - How to increase varchar size of an existing column in a database without breaking existing data?

Tags: mysql

I have a column that is currently `varchar(100)` and I want to make it `10000`.

is it as simple as

```
alter table table_name set column col_name varchar (10000);
```

I am afraid to corrupt the exiting data. Will I be ok if I run this query? Or should I do I `alter` the column another way?

Comment: Don't forget to include any other attributes that the column already has!  For example `default null` or whatever displays when you do a `show create table someTableName`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I modify the size of column in a mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279568/how-can-i-modify-the-size-of-column-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I normally use this statement:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
  CHANGE COLUMN `col_name` `col_name` VARCHAR(10000);
```

But, I think SET will work too, never have tried it. :)

Comment: Just be careful with your casing, as mysql will be happy to change the case of the column for you.

Comment: In postgres it's `ALTER TABLE \`tablename\` ALTER COLUMN \`columnname\` TYPE VARCHAR(64);` I mention it because a search not mentioning mysql got me here

Answer (score 129):

It's safe to increase the size of your varchar column. You won't corrupt your data.

If it helps your peace of mind, keep in mind, you can **always run a database backup before altering your data structures**.

By the way, correct syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY col_name VARCHAR(10000)
```

Also, if the column previously allowed/did not allow nulls, you should add the appropriate syntax to the end of the alter table statement, after the column type.

Comment: Use `show create table someTableName` to determine the additional features of the column before altering it!

Comment: Also, be careful with your case of the column, as it'll change it to whatever case you give it!  I was just bitten by that fun feature.

Comment: For safe schema changes, we roll Percona w/ `pt-online-schema-change`. It makes a copy of the table with the desired change, then renames the copy to the original table's name. Obv you can do that yourself, but it has a bunch of other nice safety checks, too.

Comment: This did not work: alter table my_table modify my_col varchar(100); This did work: alter table my_table change column my_col my_col varchar(100) not null; MySQL 5.6

Comment: @WilliamT.Mallard Sounds like you had your syntax wrong when you entered it. Did you accidentally double-up the field name in an attempt to perform a rename as well? In that case, yes, you need to use `CHANGE`.

Comment: I suppose it might be a MySQL Workbench error. The command "alter table my_table modify my_col varchar(100);" gives a squiggly red line under "varchar" and hovering gives the error message "Syntax error: unexpected 'varchar' (varchar)".

Comment: Currently with mysql 8, running `VARCHAR(10000)` gives this error in MySQL Workbench: `Error Code: 1071. Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes`. Using smaller values (for example `200`) worked.

Comment: @Paolo From MySQL docs: `The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.` I'm guessing you're already using a large portion (65535-3072=62463 used) of the space, and 3072 is what's left.

Answer (score 25):

I'd like explain the different alter table syntaxes - See the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)

For adding/removing defaults on a column:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN col_name {SET DEFAULT literal | DROP DEFAULT}
```

For renaming a column, changing it's data type and optionally changing the column order:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
CHANGE [COLUMN] old_col_name new_col_name column_definition
[FIRST|AFTER col_name]
```

For changing a column's data type and optionally changing the column order:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY [COLUMN] col_name column_definition
[FIRST | AFTER col_name]
```

Comment: +1 for giving a much more documented response with the use of different commands (`alter`, `change` and `modify`) in different situations.

Answer (score 1):

For me worked this one:

ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY fieldname VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL;

Answer (score -3):

I am using mysql and below syntax worked well for me,

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY col_name VARCHAR(12);
```

Answer (score -3):

For me this has worked-

ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name VARCHAR(50)