# Changing data type of a column without corrupting the data in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have employee table, as described below:

```
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| employee_id | int(16) unsigned      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| first_name  | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name   | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| team        | varchar(20)           | NO   |     | No Team |                |
+-------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I would like to change team's type from `varchar(20)` to `varchar(128)` without corrupting the data in the table.

How  should I do this?

Comment: it will not be corrupted since the new length is greater the old one. Additionally, they have the same type.
On the other case if the old length is greater than the new length, the data is not `corrupted` but instead truncated.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184086/mysql-how-to-increase-varchar-size-of-an-existing-column-in-a-database-without

Answer (score 0):

In such cases you can:

- create a backup of the database to make sure if something goes wrong, you still have a recent copy to work with
- save your data into a temporarily created table or column
- do the alteration and change the column
- check whether there are any differences between the temporary save and your data and cope with potential differences
- if everything was handled well, remove the temporary table/column, if not, reload the backup and start your operation from scratch again

In this particular case there should be no problems, so you might decide whether precaution should dominate.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `employee` CHANGE team team VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No Team';
```