# Warning: Data truncated for column 'src_address' at row 1

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

```
from pox.core import core
import pox.openflow.libopenflow_01 as of
import re

import datetime
import time
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy import Column, Date, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import exists
log = core.getLogger()

engine = create_engine('mysql://root@192.168.129.139/nwtopology', echo=False)
Base = declarative_base()
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class SourcetoPort(Base):
    """"""
    __tablename__ = 'source_to_port'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    port_no        = Column(Integer)
    src_address    = Column(String(16),index=True)

    #-----------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, src_address,port_no):
        """"""
        self.src_address = src_address
        self.port_no     = port_no

   #create tables
   Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    def act_like_switch (self, packet, packet_in):


"""
Implement switch-like behavior.
"""
# Learn the port for the source MAC
#print "RECIEVED FROM PORT ",packet_in.in_port , "SOURCE ",packet.src ,"DEST" , packet.dst
self.mac_to_port[packet.src]=packet_in.in_port
r_res = session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=str(packet.src)).first()
if r_res is None:
    print "inserting an entry"
    start = time.time()
    entry = SourcetoPort(src_address=str(packet.src) , port_no=packet_in.in_port)
    #add the record to the session object
    session.add(entry)
    #add the record to the session object
    session.commit()
    end = time.time()
    elapsed = end - start
    print "elapsed insert time ",elapsed
else:
    print "entry already present"
```

I have a network where I am sending packets from one host to another.The expected behaviour is that the first time the src_address,port pair should be inserted into the sql database and thereafter it should only do retrieve operation.I have tested this functionlity working correctly with a local database using sqlite.Then I shifted to a remote database using mysql.

Now I find that

```
if r_res is None:
```

is always true,meaning

r_res = session.query(SourcetoPort).filter_by(src_address=str(packet.src)).first()

is always failing.

I suspect this has something to do with some wrong query / add for mysql that is different from that for sqlite.

```
It did print out a warning as below when inserting an entry.
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py:330: Warning: Data truncated for column 'src_address' at row 1
  cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
```

I can't figure out what exactly seems to be the problem.

Based on the comments I have printed out the size of src_address that I am trying to insert.

```
 print 'length of src addreess',len(str(packet.src))
 it prints 17
```

and I have increased the size of src_address to 17,32 and 64.Still I get the same error

Comment: what is the size of your  column 'src_address'? and also the size of the data you've tried to fit in? This warning is telling you the DBMS had to cut off data to be able to put it in the respectively column. Maybe change the column's length? ;-)

Comment: I have updated the question based on your question.Still the same problem.

Comment: when you changed the length of src_address, did you just do it in the program?  Or did you change the underlying table as well?

Comment: goog question.I changed it only in the program.What is the underlying table? I haven't created an underlying table.I created a database using 'create database' from mysql server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following approach might save you time in future.

There us one more way of updating columns without recreating table - by using ALTER TABLE query.

```
alter table source_to_port modify src_address varchar(32);
```

See more discussion in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279568/how-can-i-modify-a-size-of-column-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I changed the column's length only in the program.I had to do 
either change the length of the column in the database table or delete the table(The new table created will have the correct length specified in the program.)