# 32 char limit to 140 char limit?

Tags: mysql

[image]

---

**I cannot make my update longer than 32 characters. How can I change this so it saves characters up to 140?**

This is my first ever day of working with a database so please be nice. :)

Comment: That's a nice GIF, but we can't really do anything but guess when you aren't showing us the (full) code. Is this message stored in a database? If so, it might be a length issue.

Comment: Maybe changing property of your field in table structure (phpMyAdmin): change `VARCHAR (32)` in `VARCHAR (140)` (or `CHAR`, depending of your field type)

Comment: @fusion3k I've tried looking for that but cannot find it, maybe you can guide me to it?

Comment: @Mia You'll need to find the table and column where this data is being stored in the database (check the code where it updates) - then modify the type of it to increase the length it accepts (you can do this using phpMyAdmin).

Comment: What type of database are you using (SQL, MySQL, etc.)?

Comment: @Maverick976 look at tags...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I modify the size of column in a mysql table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279568/how-can-i-modify-the-size-of-column-in-a-mysql-table)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: coherent answer]

In our phpMyAdmin, select “structure” on your table list, then select “change” at the right of your field (“Message”) and increase the “Length/Value” type.